# why is this matching past 'not a comma'?

Tags: regex

I have a string that can look like the following:

```
"1132","Fredricks, Ben","Boulder,         CO","x755593"
```

And I have the following regex which I thought should NOT match:

```
^"\d+",".*?","[^,]+"
```

But it matches the entire string. Shouldn't the `[^,]+` which means, I think "match everything thats not a comma up until a quote mark ... cause the match to fail? It encounters a comma which I thought would make it not match.

I guess my question is ... why does this match? I'm trying to find things inside the 3rd set of quotes that don't have a comma.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: What part of the string do you think *should* match?

Comment: @ghost writing regex in sublime text which uses boost syntax; also tested the same regex and string in javascript with the same result. I have a solution, but I'd like to understand why *this* doesn't work when as best as I can tell, it should. CodeGnome: it matches the entire string, it shouldn't match it at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` in `.*?` only makes the match *non greedy*.  Without it the pattern would capture as much as possible while still matching the rest.  It was probably added to avoid having that pattern match across a `"` but it doesn't *prevent* it.  If you looked at the captured strings (if you matched `"(\d+)"` etc so `$1` contain the matches) you'd see that your `.*?` matched much more than you expected (multiple fields).

Comment: oooh so it keeps going to a later quote ... I see. Yeah, I'm an idiot ... thats why changing that bit to [^"]+ works.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use an Interval Expression Instead

If you're just trying to capture the first three fields of your record, the following will work:

```
^"\d+"(,"[^"]+?"){2}
```

For example:

```
$ echo '"1132","Fredricks, Ben","Boulder,         CO","x755593"' | 
    pcregrep --only-matching '^"\d+"(,"[^"]+?"){2}'
"1132","Fredricks, Ben","Boulder,         CO"
```